# Default route at startup with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

With a brand new ASP.NET Core API application, how do you set the default route to navigate to when F5 debugging? I have the SPA being served correctly but every time the application is started with Visual Studio, it defaults to `https://localhost:44323/api/values`

There appears to be nowhere in Visual Studio to configure this. In previous versions of ASP.NET this was an option under project properties.

(The `/api/values` route being the route of the default controller setup by the template.)

Comment: Go to the project properties, Debug tab, look to the right of the checkbox that is labelled "Launch browser:" Hiding in plain sight.

Answer (score 1):

Am unsure if `launchsettings.json` is still a thing in the latest, but in the versions 1.+ i have used, have done the following. Go to `src -> you_web_project -> properties ->launchSettings.json` and edit the file.

Depending upon what you are using as your debugger which could be iis express or the .net command line, edit the settings under `launchUrl` (might be `applicationUrl` for the default iisExpress) and you should be good to go.